# do ios webviews check urls for malware before opening them?

Tags: ios, webview, safe-browsing

If I open arbitrary urls in my ios application, will I have to do my own malware/phishing/etc... checks? Does the webview (implicitly) do any work on my behalf (or would i have to switch a setting somewhere?)?

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/lpilorz/webview-security-on-ios-en

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: no.

UIWebView only has some restricts about javascript same-origin policy, and iOS has it's own SSL Certificates Validation (TLS Chain Validation) which can help UIWebView a little bit safe.

If you want to check malware, phisinng, ... you're free to do it.

Answer (score 1):

No, it uses Webkit under the hood, which does not check for malwares, but it may give you only hints on expired certificates, self-signed certificates or invalid ones.

You should implement a request filter, which performs better SSL checks for valid certificates and uses some third-party anti-malware / dangerous domains and keep them out. In that case, you just ignore "that" request.